# sidekiqを使ってmysqlのテーブルを更新する方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

sidekiqを使って非同期にメールを送る処理を作っています。メールを送信するときに結果をテーブルに書き込んでいます。データベースは開発環境ではsqlite、本番環境ではmysqlを使います。開発環境では問題なく動作したのですが、本番環境では、sidekiqを動かす時に「sqlite3」をインストールしないと「Gem::LoadError: Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter」とエラーが出てしまい、sqliteを入れるとsidekiqは動作するのですが、キューを処理するときに「ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table」とエラーが出てしまいます。おそらくsqliteのテーブルを探そうとしてしまっていると思うのですが、sidekiqでmysqlのテーブルを更新するようにするにはどのようにすればよいでしょうか？Railsのバージョンは4.2.7です。

Answer (score 1):

下記のコマンドでsidekiqを起動することで解決しました。

```
bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml --environment=production
```

以前は、

```
bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml RAILS_ENV=production
```

のように起動していたのですが、production環境であることを伝える形式が間違っていたようです。